# Some Error in Php code

Tags: php, html, css, web

first file is index.php

```
<?php include('loginform.php');?>
```

second file is loginform.php

```
<?php
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username"><br>
<label>Password></label>
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="login">
</form>
<a href="register.php">Register here</a>
</body>
</html>
?>
```

third file is register.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>FirstName</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
<label>LastName</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
<label>Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email"><br>
<label>UserName</label>
<input type="text" name="username"><br>
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have three files in the project first file is the index file which is shown whenever the user opens the website It contains two things login form and a link
ie register here.So i have wrapped all this in one single php file loginform.php
and included it in my index.php file so when I execute this in my localhost web server it shows a error like this
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\loginform.php on line 2
How can I tackle this problem please tell me?

Comment: Have a look online for some php tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `loginform.php` file isn't a PHP source file, it's just an HTML file. Remove the enclosing `<?php` and `?>` from it and you should be OK.